# Proving a statement on differentiation

Tags: analysis, derivatives

> Suppose $f : (0, 1) → \mathbb R$ is differentiable on $(0, 1)$ and that for $x,y ∈ (0,1)$ with $x < y$ we have that $f′(x) < 0$ and $f′(y) > 0$. Show that there exists $z ∈ (x, y)$ such that
>
> $$f(z) = \inf\{f(a) : a \in [x,y]\}$$

I'm not really sure how to start this, I've looked at a few theorems like Rolle's and the mean value theorem but don't know which one to use?

Comment: erhh, I know where the statement is going. But shouldn't continuous functions over a close interval attain their min/max value over the interval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f$ is differentiable on $(0,1)$ it is continuous on $[x,y]$. Thus $f$ attains its infimum on $[x,y]$.

The conditions on the derivatives imply that the infimum can't occur at either endpoint.